# How to catch invalid Elasticsearch queries?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Given an invalid query, Elasticsearch's Java API (1.1.0) throws a `SearchPhaseExecutionException`. This exception has no "cause", but a "message" like this one:

`Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed; shardFailures {[bwUSN171Ru6rY1-su5-48A][f2f0i20hrf][0]: SearchParseException[[f2f0i20hrf][0]: from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"size":0,"query":{"bool":{"must":{"term":{"count":""}}}}}]]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: ""]; }`

How can I distinguish invalid queries from other errors, other than doing a string search for `SearchParseException`, or [validating](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-validate.html) the query first?

Comment: The cause is the `nested` exception (`NumberFormatException` above). However, it's usually not as useful as that the one above (which itself does not give away that `"count"` was the field missing the numeric value) and clearly not usefully parsable in the string. I realize this isn't so useful, which is why it's not an answer.

Comment: The problem is, there is no `NumberFormatException` (or even `SearchParseException`) object, as far as I can see (`getCause()` returns `null`). I suppose I could try to parse the `getMessage()` string, but was hoping for a better solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use validate query before query execution in that case:

```
ValidateQueryRequest validateQueryRequest = new ValidateQueryRequest(indexName);
validateQueryRequest.source(jsonContent);
validateQueryRequest.explain(true);

ActionFuture<ValidateQueryResponse> future = client.admin().indices().validateQuery(validateQueryRequest); // the client is org.elasticsearch.client.Client
ValidateQueryResponse response = future.get(); // typical java future as response
System.out.println(response.isValid()); // true or false
System.out.println(response.getQueryExplanation().size()); // size of explanations why the query is incorrect
```

QueryExplanation.getError() provides something like that (for the query where I'm trying to use text with number field range):

> org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [bill_d20160227t123119] Failed to parse; java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "TEST"

More about validation API you will find at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-validate.html

Hope it helps!